# React filter large dataset without re-render (Too many re-renders error)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, papaparse

I have a really large array of objects, parsed (PapaParse) from a CSV:

```
import { readRemoteFile } from 'react-papaparse'    

const [studentData, setStudentData] = useState(null)
const [filteredStudents, setFilteredStudents] = useState([])
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)   

useEffect(() => { 
  grabData()
}, [])    

const grabData = () => {
  readRemoteFile('my-data.csv', {
    complete: (results) => { // this method gets called once file is finished parsing
      setStudentData(results.data)
      setLoading(false)
    }
  }
}
```

I want to filter the student data and only show students with the name 'Amber' for example:

```
const getFilteredStudents = (name) => {
  let updatedStudents = studentData.filter((student) => {
    return student.name === name
  }
  setFilteredStudents(updatedStudents)
  // Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
}

if (!loading) {
  getFilteredStudents('Amber')
}
```

In the above codeblock, called `setFilteredStudents(updatedStudents)` causes a react error.

Finally I just want to render only the filtered students in the component:

```
render (
  <div>
  { filteredStudents ?
    filteredStudents.map((student, index) => {
      <div key={index}>
        student.name
      </div>
    } : null
  }
  </div>
)
```

Comment: We need the context for that `getFilteredStudents` function. Where is it being called?

Comment: You are almost certainly modifying something in a useEffect hook that triggers the infinite render, but you haven't posted enough for us to say.

Comment: I've updated the original post. I have a conditional which calls the `getFilteredStudents()` method if the CSV has completed parsing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because your are calling

```
if (!loading) {
  getFilteredStudents('Amber')
}
```

everytime the component renders, which triggers a new => getFilteredStudents which does => setFilteredStudents resulting into a new re-render and an infinite loop

you should instead do

```
const grabData = () => {
  readRemoteFile('my-data.csv', {
    complete: (results) => { // this method gets called once file is finished parsing
      setStudentData(results.data);
    }
  }
}
```

and just call `getFilteredStudents('Amber')` with a button..

Comment: Literally figured this out as you were posting this. Your explanation is extremely useful. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the conditional:

```
if (!loading) {
  getFilteredStudents('Amber')
}
```

Removed it and it seems to be working. Now I just need a much better way of rendering the data, because there are about 5000 Amber objects